# Pyspark on Spark 2.1.1, StructFields in StructType are always nullable

Tags: pyspark

I'm creating a StructType using several StructFields -- the name and datatype seem to work fine, but regardless of setting nullable to False in each StructField the resulting schema reports nullable is True for each StructField.

Can anyone explain why?  THANKS!

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, FloatType, TimestampType

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder \
  .master("local") \
  .appName("SparkSession") \
  .getOrCreate()


dfStruct = StructType().add("date", TimestampType(), False)
dfStruct.add("open", FloatType(), False)
dfStruct.add("high", FloatType(), False)
dfStruct.add("low", FloatType(), False)
dfStruct.add("close", FloatType(), False)
dfStruct.add("ticker",  StringType(), False)

#print elements of StructType -- reports nullable is false
for d in dfStruct: print d

#data looks like this:
#date,open,high,low,close,ticker
# 2014-10-14 23:20:32,7.14,9.07,0.0,7.11,ARAY
# 2014-10-14 23:20:36,9.74,10.72,6.38,9.25,ARC
# 2014-10-14 23:20:38,31.38,37.0,28.0,30.94,ARCB
# 2014-10-14 23:20:44,15.39,17.37,15.35,15.3,ARCC
# 2014-10-14 23:20:49,5.59,6.5,5.31,5.48,ARCO

#read csv file and apply dfStruct as the schema
df = sparkSession.read.csv(path = "/<path tofile>/stock_data.csv", \
                           schema = dfStruct, \
                           sep = ",", \
                           ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace = True, \
                           ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace = True \
                           )

#reports nullable as True!
df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19950) in Spark. There is currently an [open pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17293) in Spark aiming to fix this issue. If you really need your fields to be non-nullable, try:

```
#read csv file and apply dfStruct as the schema
df = sparkSession.read.csv(path = "/<path tofile>/stock_data.csv", \
                       schema = dfStruct, \
                       sep = ",", \
                       ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace = True, \
                       ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace = True \
                       ).rdd.toDF(dfStruct)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the speed of conversions like this, so I wouldn't use it for terabyte-scale data, but if you're just reading csv files, it should work pretty well.